# Navigation controller stack issue after memory warning

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I use UINavigationController in my program,when I situated on forth or fifth controller in navigation stack,program recieve memory warning and I can't go backwards. I press back button, navigation bar animation is taking place,but controller isn't being popped,I still see old view. Can anyone help me handle this problem?

My subviews has property:

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) UITableView *searchTableView;
@property (nonatomic,retain) UISegmentedControl *categorySegmentedControl;
@property (nonatomic,retain) UISearchBar *searchTableBar;
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIView *footerView;
@property (nonatomic,retain) UINavigationItem *navigationItem;
```

My viewDidUnload method

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
  [super viewDidUnload];
  self.searchTableView = nil;
  self.categorySegmentedControl = nil;
  self.searchTableBar = nil;
  self.navigationItem = nil;
  self.footerView = nil;
}
```

My dealloc

```
-(void)dealloc
{
  [super dealloc];
  [searchTableView release];
  [categorySegmentedControl release];
  [searchTableBar release];
  [navigationItem release];
  [footerView release];
  [currentValues release];
}
```

And I had noticed strange regularity - this bug appears only when I move from view without tab bar to view with tab bar.

Comment: Do your viewControllers handle viewDidLoad and viewDidUnload properly?

Comment: yes,I have self.myIBOtlet = nil in my viewDidUnload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may be doing some setup in your controller's viewDidLoad and/or releasing stuff in viewDidUnload that should be done in initWithNibName:bundle and dealloc instead.

viewDidLoad and viewDidUnload are not called when your controller is created and destroyed, they are called when the view inside your controller is created and destroyed, and this can happen at any time, especially if you receive a memory warning when the view controller is in the background (e.g. not the top view in a navigation controller).

Make sure that you write your controllers in such a way that if the viewDidUnload gets called, or if the viewDidLoad gets called multiple times, you won't lose data or break anything.

Sorry if this answer is a bit vague, but if you post the code for your view controllers, I can probably give you more specific advice.

Comment: I haven't something linked to my view states in my viewDidLoad method,but I have self.myIBOutlet = nil for all IBOutlets in my viewDidUnload method.

Comment: Are you maybe settings some things to nil in your viewDidUnload that aren't views? You should only set views to nil in viewDidUnload, not view controllers or other properties. Try pasting your viewDidUnload methods into your question and I'll take a look.

Comment: Hmm. Looks pretty-much correct. Not sure about self.navigationItem though, are you setting that in your nib? Normally that's created automatically.

Comment: Yes, but viewController already has a property called navigationItem, so I'm wondering if overriding that property with one of the same name might relate to what's going wrong. It may be a non-issue, it's just a theory.

Comment: I really don't how using custom navigationItem can call this problem but deleting self.navigationItem seems to solve my problem! I simulate  memoryWarning in simulator,it works,can't wait to try it on device tomorrow!Great thanks!

Comment: According to the docs for UIViewController, if you want to override the navigationItem you should override the navigationItem method and return your own navigationItem from that method. try that instead of creating a new navigationItem property. You can just create an outlet for it with a different name and then return that value from your navigationItem method.